# Wordpress include javascript file in a add_shortcode function

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I try to include a js-file in a shortcode function in my plugin, unfortunately without success. :-(

plugin:

```
function send_mail(){

$input = "<input type='submit' value='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>";
wp_register_script('myscript', plugins_url('/js/myscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);

return $input;
}

add_shortcode('send', 'send_mail');
```

front-end-page.php

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[send]');
```

When i load the front-end-page, there is no js included. :-( What I am doing wrong?

Thanks for your helf,
Yab86

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check shrotcode existence in a post using has_shrtocode

```
function send_mail(){
    $input = "<input type='submit' value='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>";
    return $input;
}
add_shortcode('send', 'send_mail');

function check_shortcode_existence() {
    global $post;
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'send') && !is_admin() ) {
        wp_register_script('myscript', plugins_url('/js/myscript.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
        wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'check_shortcode_existence');
```